# Visual Studio 2013 can't select separate project in project explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I created my first project I could easily hit the F5 button to compile and build it. But when I tried to hit F5 to compile a second project, it only built the first one. Looking at the project explorer it seems like the first project is selected, by way of it's name being bolded. How do I select the second project so that I can use the shortcut F5 to build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F5 key in Visual Studio maps to 'Start Debugging'. The IDE has a concept of a 'StartUp' project. This is the project that will build and run if you hit F5. The current Startup project is bolded in the Solution Explorer. If your second project is a executable or DLL, you can right click on it in the 'Solution Explorer', and select 'Set as Startup Project'.